# Create a 6 digit sequence number in c#

Tags: c#

How do i create a six digit sequence number in c# ?

Is there any other way than storing a string in the database like "000000" and later on incrementing it through the last inserted value ?

Comment: most databases support sequences... and costum sequnces...

Comment: an auto-incrementing value? just use an `int not null IDENTITY(1,1)` or similar; worry about the leading 0s in the UI, not the DB

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a plain old number as a sequence, this is what your DB will provide. If you want to display it with six digits, just call: `yourNumber.ToString("D6")`

([see docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx#DFormatString))